# paintComponent() wont draw

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

After looking around for a bit, I finally found out how to actually call the `paintComponent()` method. The problem I'm having right now, is that the line `g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 6);` is not actually drawing the rectangle. I put two `System.out.println` above and below this line of code to see if actually got to that line, and it did.

Here is the constructor of the class. the paintComponent() method is called at the end

```
View(Model m)
{
    this.m = m;

    setTitle("Word Guesssing");
    super.setSize( new Dimension (475, 500) );


    drawPanel  = new JPanel ( new MigLayout() );
    guessPanel = new JPanel ( new MigLayout() );
    wordPanel  = new JPanel ( new MigLayout() );
    guessedLettersPanel = new JPanel ( new MigLayout() );



    setLetterTextFields(); //Adds the letter JTextFields to an ArrayList in the Model class.
    addToGuessPanel(); //Method where components are added to the guessPanel.
    addToWordPanel(); //Method where components are added to the wordPanel. 
    addToGuessedLettersPanel(); //Method where components are added to the guessedLettersPanel.


    //Sets a boarder for each panel.
    wordPanel.setBorder  (new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    drawPanel.setBorder  (new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    guessPanel.setBorder (new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    guessedLettersPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

    //Sets the sizes for each panel
    drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (475, 500));
    wordPanel.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension(450, 50) );
    guessPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(350, 100) );
    guessedLettersPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(125, 600) );


    setRadioButtonGroup();

    addToPane();

    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);

    paintComponent(drawPanel.getGraphics());
}
```

here is the paintComponent() method

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    System.out.println("here 1");
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 6);
    System.out.println("here 2");
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call paintComponent() directly, and especially from the constructor. You should call repaint() which makes sure that all the components are drawn properly. You're using the paintComponent() very oddly, calling the method of class View with the graphics of drawPanel, so I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried using repaint() after you suggested it. The two System.out.println's that I have in the method aren't even being displayed on the console now. Oddly enough, the first time I tried using repaint() for paintComponent() it gave me a complier error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to `repaint()` as Kayaman suggested, but probably a bigger issue is that in paintComponent you don't call the superclass's paintComponent.  Try adding `super.paintComponent(g)` to the top of that function.

EDIT:  you should have it extend a JPanel, and then add it to a JFrame if you want it to show up.  A good way of thinking about this is that the JFRame is the window, but the JComponents (an JPanel is a JComponent) tell the window what to draw

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work. super.paintComponent(g) gives me a complier error and tells me to change it to super.paintComponents(g)

Comment: What class does `View` extend?  In order for you to be able to use paintComponent(), its superclass should have paintComponent()...

Comment: It's extending JFrame

Comment: You should be extending JPanel if you want to draw to it, see my edit.